# How to create this nice colorful glass material?

Tags: modeling, mesh, glass

[image: i want to Refer to this img]

My glass object is too dark. I tried to use the light path node to limit the shadow and reflection to make it brighter, but it doesn't have a good real shadow. I don't know why.

Thank you

Answer (score 11):

I think I'm not too far with this setup (rendered with *Eevee*, it might be slightly different with *Cycles*): I've made a mix between *Glass*, *Transparent* and *Glossy*. It also needs *Volume Scatter* to give it this blurry depth:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Oh you're good :). The volume scatter is a nice touch.

Comment: thnaks, it lacks a bit of luminescence though

Comment: Since Emission nodes can be plugged into Volume maybe mix in a tiny bit one of those? Just a thought.

Comment: yes I tried that but it didn't give what we see on the original picture